# Create new method in the initialization of a delegate list

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a list of delegates:

```
public List<Func<bool>> Requirements { get; set; };
```

Now when I try to initialize it with an existing method, it works perfectly:

```
Requirements = new List<Func<bool>>() { obj.IsValid };
```

But how can I create a new method in this initialization and pass it to the list?
Pseudocode:

```
Requirements = new List<Func<bool>>() { bool() {return true} };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `bool() {return true}` is, but it's not the syntax for an inline delegate. Use a lambda, such as `() => true`.

Comment: It's close to C# 10's new syntax... `bool () => { return true; }` is valid. C# 10 allows you to specify the return type.

Comment: Thanks canton7. `() => true` works perfectly. @madreflection `bool () => { return true; }` might be valid c# but won't work in this case.

Comment: It's identical to `() => true` except that it's more explicit on a couple things. The only reason it wouldn't work is if you're not using C# 10. I'm not suggesting that you use it, mind you... but your example was *so close* to that syntax, it seemed like that was what you wanted, so I pointed out how close it was to valid C# 10 syntax.

Comment: Yup, my mistake. `bool () => { return true; }` works perfectly too, just tested it wit C# 10. Thanks for the reply.